# How to write a MongoDB Query in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

in MongoHub i can use this query to find my result.

```
db.cache.collection01.find({'md5': "\u0000\u0000\b :\u0007\"" }).skip(0).limit(30)
```

How can i do it in PHP ? i tried this:

```
// Connect to test database
$m = new Mongo("mongodb://$dbhost");
$db = $m->$dbname;

// select the collection
$collection = $db->collection01;

// pull a cursor query
// search for fruits
$query = array('md5' => '"\u0000\u0000\b :\u0007\""');
$cursor = $collection->find($query);


foreach($cursor as $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Which client you're using? It's not this one http://php.net/manual/de/mongocollection.find.php

Comment: You have to double escape those `"`

Comment: Yes i'm using that. But i dont get any result.,

Comment: $query = array('md5' => '\"\u0000\u0000\b :\u0007\"\"');

doesnt work,too..

Comment: i figured out: i imported this data from mysql. this was a binary(16)